# Biztalk HL7 : How to manage various message types?

Tags: biztalk, hl7

I'm relatively new to Biztalk and HL7 and still learning...I'm really hoping to find a bit of advice.

So far I can send and receive an ADT A01 with MLLP no problem in a test project  (basic orchestration/multipart message/construct with ADTA01_to_mysystem map technique).

I'm now hoping to expend the development to handle other message types in an efficient way.

I read many concepts like dynamic mapping, canonical schemas, custom pipelines, ESB, etc, but I'm still a bit lost.

This link offers 2 solutions: [Biztalk message agnostic orchestration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066826/biztalk-message-agnostic-orchestration)

I was really hoping if someone could give more details about the two methods proposed.

Specifically, in a receive scenario,

1. If the message comes as untyped in the orchestration, how do I handle the XML after the receive shape to construct and map to my schema ?
2. I'm not too familiar with the canonical approach. Could someone elaborate a bit more please ?

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me to example of code or orchestrations, solution samples, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Claude
I use Biztalk 2013

Comment: Your question is very broad. Try adding some information of code samples you've tried that aren't working and what errors you are getting.

Comment: What do you handle the XML for? You can easily promote properties from a pipeline component for later use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

We are not using HL7 but we are using canonical message approach. Basically we are accepting any xml then transforming it to canonical message shape and then message is processed in the orchestration.

We are using also ESB where we are applying maps before message enters orchestration.

Hope this makes sense.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Thank you. If you have references or documentation, that would be great.